# Como fazer join com 3 tabelas no Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho 3 tabelas no meu banco de dados, que são:

Tabela **user**:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Usuário 1 |
| 2 | Usuário 2 |

Tabela **pack**:

| id | name | id_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pacote 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Pacote 2 | 1 |

`id_user` é a `foreign key` da tabela com referência para a tabela `user`.

Tabela **order**:

| id | name | id_user | id_pack |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pedido 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Pedido 2 | 2 | null |
| 3 | Pedido 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | Pedido 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | Pedido 5 | 1 | 1 |

`id_user` e `id_pack` são as `foreign key` da tabela com referência para a tabela `user` e para a tabela `pack`.

Como posso montar um código SQL para exibir os pacotes (tabela **pack**) que contem os pedidos (tabela **order**) vinculados a ela que estão vinculados ao usuário de `id` 1?

Eu tentei o seguinte código:

```
select `u`.*, `p`.*, `o`.* from `user` as `u`
inner join `pack` as `p` on `u`.`id` = `p`.`id_user` 
inner join `order` as `o` on `p`.`id` = `o`.`id_pack`
WHERE `u`.`id` = 1
```

Comment: Tente dessa forma:   
`select "u".*, "p".*, "o".* 
  from "pack" as "p"
  inner join "order" as "o" on "p"."id" = "o"."id_pack"
  inner join "user" as "u" on "p"."id_user" = "u"."id" 
  WHERE "p"."id_user" = 1 `

Comment: @ClarckMaciel o resultado retornou vazio.

Comment: Seria interessante se tivesse a estrutura criada em um site como o http://sqlfiddle.com/.   Desta forma poderíamos fazer a simulação do comando. Cria as estruturas das tabelas, faz os inserts dos dados para teste.

Comment: @ClarckMaciel já vou providenciar e atualizo aqui.

Comment: Você tem duas tabelas que possuem o campo `id_user`, você quer filtrar com base em qual usuário? Usuário da tabela `pack` ou da tabela `order`?

Comment: Consegui colocar lá e fazer retornar o resultado, o estranho é que no meu banco de dados não retorna nada. Veja o link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e91e8/1

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124240/discussion-between-wendell-and-clarck-maciel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
select `u`.*, `p`.*, `o`.*    
  from `pack` as `p`   
 inner join `order` as `o` on `p`.`id` = `o`.`id_pack`   
 inner join `user` as `u` on `p`.`id_user` = `u`.`id`    
 WHERE `p`.`id_user` = 1
```